# What's the meaning of "Sure looks like it went over, too"?

Tags: meaning, usage

> Shouldn't that be a good thing, telling somebody, "no thanks
>   required"?
>
> **Sure looks like it went over, too.** Look at you. You're sure making the
>   rounds.

I found this line from the movie, [*As Good As It Gets*](http://movie-sounds.org/comedy-movie-sounds/as-good-as-it-gets-1997/sure-looks-like-it-went-over-too), and I'm curious about this phrase "it went over".

"went over" has various meanings such as 'look at(documents) carefully', 'to study or explain', but I think they don't match in the dialogue I quoted.

Answer (score 2):

From the passage, it seems someone (let's say Carol) has done something for someone, was thanked, and replied

> No thanks required

This was probably met with a smile from the person doing the thanking.

The person Carol is speaking with says

> **Sure looks like it went over**
>   Sure looks like it went over *(well)*
>   Sure looks like it went over *(a treat)*

Meaning what Carol said was **well received**, her reply was **approved**

The expression

> *something* **go over** *description*

is used to describe a **reaction** to the mentioned ***something***

> The new play *went over* **well** with the critics
>   The acting *went over* **like a lead balloon**